# SQL UPDATE with Joined tables: Out of Memory Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to UPDATE a table in pSQL and getting all sorts of memory/execution errors.

The odd thing is, the SELECT query powering the update is very quick. I'm sure I just don't really get what is going on under the hood.

Some context.

---

### Relevant tables

```
address_book:
loan_id,
county,
zip
---
loan:
id
---
loan_property:
loan_id,
property_id
---
property:
id,
zip,
county
```

### Goal

The goal is to update the property table's *zip* & *county* with the values in address_book. The address_book has a loan_id, which is the join to property.

---

### The SQL

Let's look at a simple SELECT

```
WITH ab AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
    left(ab.loan_id, 6) AS loan_id,
    ab.zip AS zip,
    ab.county AS county
FROM 
    address_book ab
WHERE
    ab.address IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT ab.county, p.name

FROM property p
INNER JOIN loan_property lp ON lp.property_id = p.id
INNER JOIN loan           l ON lp.loan_id     = l.id
INNER JOIN               ab ON ab.loan_id     = l.id
WHERE 
    l.id = ab.loan_id
```

This works perfectly and is very quick (.4 sec on ~10k records)

Let's take the above and make it an UPDATE call:

```
WITH ab AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
    left(ab.loan_id, 6) AS loan_id,
    ab.zip AS zip,
    ab.county AS county
FROM 
    address_book ab
WHERE
    ab.address IS NOT NULL
)

UPDATE property
SET zip=ab.zip, county=ab.county

FROM property p
INNER JOIN loan_property lp ON lp.property_id = p.id
INNER JOIN loan           l ON lp.loan_id     = l.id
INNER JOIN               ab ON ab.loan_id     = l.id
WHERE 
    l.id = ab.loan_id
```

This update runs for 2 min and then typically fails based on

> SQL Error [53200]: ERROR: out of memory

Is there a more optimal way to run this update? Even if I have to batch by LIMIT/OFFSET or save the SELECT results to a table and then perform an UPDATE directly from that table - what's the way to run this update without hitting memory errors?

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.6) do **not** repeat the target table in the UPDATE statement:

```
...
UPDATE property
   SET zip = ab.zip, 
       county = ab.county
FROM loan_property lp
   JOIN loan l ON lp.loan_id = l.id
   JOIN ab ON ab.loan_id = l.id
WHERE lp.property_id = p.id
```

Comment: As the query is presented, the update will *randomly* update the zip and country for properties with multiple loans and/or loans with multiple address_books.

Comment: @TheImpaler: still, the original query generates a cross join of the `property` table with itself which is most probably the reason for the slow update and and the out of memory error

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have properties with lots of loans.  Run:

```
select property_id, count(*)
from loan_property
group by property_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

The question is which information you want to fill the information in from.

It is also possible that you have loans with many addresses.  The `select distinct` is suspicious there.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Gordon_Linoff - Actually, most of the records are 1 to 1 with a handful with 2 or 3. Regarding the SELECT Distinct, that's because of other columns in the address_book table.

Comment: And what happens with those properties with 2 or 3 loans? Which zip and country do you pick?

Comment: Good question @TheImpaler In theory they should have the same zip/county in the address_book.

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer is similar to the answer from @a_horse_with_no_name - something odd in re-referencing the target table.

I actually combined the FROM clause in the update into another aliased SELECT call, like so:

```
WITH ab as (
SELECT distinct
    p.id as p_id, 
    ab.county as county, 
    ab.zip as zip
FROM 
    address_book ab
inner join loan l on ab.loan_id = l.id
inner join loan_property lp on loan_id = l.id
inner join property p on lp.property_id = p.id
WHERE
    ab.address IS NOT null
    and l.id = ab.loan_id
)

UPDATE property
SET county__c=ab.county, zip_code__c=ab.zip
FROM ab
WHERE ab.p_id = id
```

Separating the joins (especially with the target table) out of the FROM call in the update fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The most preferrable is to group, order and limit records then use the same in your update statement i guess there could be lots that is the main reason you are getting out of memory. Because update works row by row hence, redundant data is letting the update to work more and worsen the time limit. So, Best option to group your records in update as `select` statement is taking less time already so theres no point optimising it. Try like the below sample

```
      WITH xyz AS (
      Select zip,property from property p
    INNER JOIN loan_property lp ON lp.property_id = p.id
     INNER JOIN loan           l ON lp.loan_id     = l.id
        INNER JOIN               ab ON ab.loan_id     = l.id
   WHERE 
    l.id = ab.loan_id group by some_value/order by zip)

    UPDATE xyz
     SET zip=ab.zip, county=ab.county
```